# Calculating the Euclidean distance between SOME entries of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, distance

I am a bit new to numpy and I am trying to calculate the pairwaise distance between some of the elements of a numpy array.

I have a numpy n x 3 array with n 3D cartesian coordinates (x,y,z) representing particles in a grid. Some of these particles move as the program runs and I need to keep track of the distances of the ones that move. I hold a list of integers with the index of the particles that have moved.

I am aware of pdist but this calculates the distance between every pair of particles, which would be inefficient as only some of them have moved. Ideally, for example, if only 1,2 have moved then I would only calculate the distance of 1 with 2...N and 2 with 3...N

What would be the most efficient way of doing this? Right now I have a double loop which doesn't seem ideal...

`for i in np.nditer(particles_moved):
    particles = particles[particles!=i]
    for j in np.nditer(particles):
        distance(xyz,i, j)`

Thanks

Comment: numpy.linalg.norm(a - b) where a and b are np.array([x, y, z])

Comment: But I would be stuck with the loops still

Comment: Can you provide a, minimal, example of the inputs and the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want (create new axis and use broadcasting for full vectorization):

```
import numpy as np

particles = np.arange(12).reshape((-1,3))
moved = np.array([0,2])
np.linalg.norm(particles[moved][:,None,:]-particles[None,:,:], axis=-1)

array([[  0.        ,   5.19615242,  10.39230485,  15.58845727],
       [ 10.39230485,   5.19615242,   0.        ,   5.19615242]])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't to use a jit compiler, here is an example using Numba

```
@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def distance(Paticle_coords,indices_moved):
  dist_res=np.empty((indices_moved.shape[0],Paticle_coords.shape[0]),dtype=Paticle_coords.dtype)

  for i in range(indices_moved.shape[0]):
    Koord=Paticle_coords[indices_moved[i],:]
    dist_res[i,:]=np.sqrt((Koord[0]-Paticle_coords[:,0])**2+(Koord[1]-Paticle_coords[:,1])**2+(Koord[2]-Paticle_coords[:,2])**2)

  return dist_res
```

**Performance compared to Julien's solution**

```
#Create Data
Paticle_coords=np.random.rand(10000000,3)
indices_moved=np.array([0,5,6,3,7],dtype=np.int64)
```

This gives on my Core i7-4771 0.15s for the Numba solution and 2.4s for Julien's solution.

Comment: Thank you. Are the loops with numba as fast as in C?

Comment: They are normally in the same range. Each compiler optimizes a problem a bit differently and compiler options are also relevant. For this problem Intel SVL may be of high interest to get a fast sqrt function. http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/performance-tips.html

Comment: So could I just write:
 @nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True) 
for i in np.nditer(particles_moved):
    particles = particles[particles!=i]
    for j in np.nditer(particles):
        distance(xyz,i, j)

Comment: The simple variants of nditer should work (1 Argument) https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html But benchmark the performance compared to the standard approach shown in my answer.